# Разделить параграф на две колонки

Tags: html, css

Не могу найти в интернете как разделить один параграф на две колонки, не создавая двух дополнительных параграфов.

Как исходные данные есть:

```css
.two{

}
```

```html
<p class="two">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vehicula, nibh nec aliquam bibendum, lectus urna fringilla dolor, ut bibendum ligula ex pellentesque neque. Pellentesque purus leo, luctus et malesuada et, blandit quis est. Morbi ornare enim malesuada odio gravida porttitor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec nec sapien vulputate, tempus mauris non, congue metus. In vulputate lacinia lectus, sit amet feugiat justo volutpat et. Nullam congue ultrices quam, eget interdum metus viverra vel. Nunc diam ex, efficitur non urna vitae, egestas molestie tortor. Maecenas tincidunt pharetra ex, vulputate hendrerit odio placerat nec. Nam vestibulum nulla at libero aliquet, nec eleifend turpis venenatis. Fusce pellentesque dignissim massa ut vestibulum. Duis dapibus orci vitae auctor dapibus. Donec commodo libero ante, nec convallis tortor fermentum in. Proin tortor neque, accumsan at sapien eget, porta placerat est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse tempus imperdiet metus, ut posuere nisi tincidunt et.
</p>
```

Для чего мне это нужно?
Чтобы написав текст в `<p>...</p>` и не разделял бы его вручную на две колонки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй `column-count`

```css
.two {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<p class="two">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vehicula, nibh nec aliquam bibendum, lectus urna fringilla dolor, ut bibendum ligula ex pellentesque neque. Pellentesque purus leo, luctus et malesuada et, blandit quis est. Morbi ornare enim
  malesuada odio gravida porttitor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec nec sapien vulputate, tempus mauris non, congue metus. In vulputate lacinia lectus, sit amet feugiat justo volutpat et. Nullam
  congue ultrices quam, eget interdum metus viverra vel. Nunc diam ex, efficitur non urna vitae, egestas molestie tortor. Maecenas tincidunt pharetra ex, vulputate hendrerit odio placerat nec. Nam vestibulum nulla at libero aliquet, nec eleifend turpis
  venenatis. Fusce pellentesque dignissim massa ut vestibulum. Duis dapibus orci vitae auctor dapibus. Donec commodo libero ante, nec convallis tortor fermentum in. Proin tortor neque, accumsan at sapien eget, porta placerat est. In hac habitasse platea
  dictumst. Suspendisse tempus imperdiet metus, ut posuere nisi tincidunt et.
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Comment: @Air, желательно ещё префиксы дописать (`-webkit-`, `-moz-`), а так в целом свойство самое то

Comment: @Arthur Да это я уже сам добавлю)

Comment: @Arthur, я уже и не вспомню, когда мне приходилось префиксы дописывать в реальном проекте....

Comment: @Air, для этого есть `WebPack` или автопрефиксеры=)
В прочем стоит пока что, если ты конечно за `user friendly interface`

Comment: Конечно за, друг мой...))  А `webpack` - это вещь)))  Я кайфую от него