# Как сделать список опций в две колонки на CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

HTML:

```html
<div class="size_block">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>s</label>
    <input type="checkbox"><label>m</label>
    <input type="checkbox"><label>l</label>
    <input type="checkbox"><label>xl</label>
    <input type="checkbox"><label>xxl</label> 
    <input type="checkbox"><label>xxxl</label>
</div>
```

Всего 6 размеров. Как сделать отображение размеров в две колонки по 3 размера, причем в первой колонке `s`,`m`,`l` и во второй `xl`,`xxl`,`xxxl`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разделить параграф на две колонки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906624/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @Air тут не параграф все-таки, больше про сетки речь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.size_block {
  column-count: 2;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="size_block">
  <label><input type="checkbox">s</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox">m</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox">l</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox">xl</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox">xxl</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox">xxxl</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1.** [CSS Multiple Columns](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

```css
.size_block {
    column-count: 2;
}

.size_block label {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="size_block">
    <label><input type="checkbox">s</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">m</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">l</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">xl</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">xxl</label> 
    <label><input type="checkbox">xxxl</label>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2.** CSS Flex колонки и ограничение высоты

```css
.size_block {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 60px;
}

.size_block label {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="size_block">
    <label><input type="checkbox">s</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">m</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">l</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">xl</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">xxl</label> 
    <label><input type="checkbox">xxxl</label>
</div>
```

**Вариант 3.** CSS Flex ряды и `order`

```css
.size_block {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.size_block label {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}

.size_block label:nth-child(1) {
    order: 1;
}

.size_block label:nth-child(2) {
    order: 3;
}

.size_block label:nth-child(3) {
    order: 5;
}

.size_block label:nth-child(4) {
    order: 2;
}

.size_block label:nth-child(5) {
    order: 4;
}

.size_block label:nth-child(6) {
    order: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="size_block">
    <label><input type="checkbox">s</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">m</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">l</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">xl</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">xxl</label> 
    <label><input type="checkbox">xxxl</label>
</div>
```

**Вариант 4.** CSS Grid

```css
.size_block {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.size_block label {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="size_block">
    <label><input type="checkbox">s</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">m</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">l</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">xl</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">xxl</label> 
    <label><input type="checkbox">xxxl</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно без доваления лишних контейнеров

Comment: инпуты в лейблы можно оборачивать? @ArturHan

Comment: Да, главное, чтобы конечный результат был нормальный

Comment: @ArturHan столько реализаций будет достаточно? =)