# Как сделать список с подсписком неизвестного кол. элементов в 2 столбца - Решено

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

Есть список элементов с подсписком. Из-за разного количества элементов подсписка высота элементов списка разная. Нужно сделать в 2 столбца, чтобы прокручивать вниз до конца.
Если делаю на флексах в строку - высота разная - некрасиво. Если в столбик - то нужно фиксировать высоту, чтобы переносились элементы во второй столбик.
В общем, ПРОШУ ПОМОЩИ. Пример ниже в коде, и здесь он же:
https://codepen.io/stivman/pen/abBdYdE
Делаю каталог сайта. И если использовать `column-count: 2;`, то получается так, что заголовок категории у меня внизу первого столбца, а его подэлементы вверху второго столбца - некрасиво и непонятно. В коде на [codepen](https://codepen.io/stivman/pen/abBdYdE) это видно.

Вижу решение только через JS - считывать ширину элемента, и если она больше двух столбцов, то добавлять высоту. Но хотелось бы обойтись средствами CSS.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list {
  border: 1px solid green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 900px;

/*   display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px; */
}

.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.second-list__item {
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
    <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
      <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
      <li class='list__item'>
    <ul class='second-list'>
      <span class='title'>элемент списка</span>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
      <li class='second-list__item'>какой-то элемент подсписка</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: А если ``.list {  column-count: 2; }`` ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разделить параграф на две колонки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906624/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Спасибо. 
Но данный способ дробит элемент.
например вот: https://codepen.io/stivman/pen/LYbNZJX
тут я сделал вместо вложенных элементов просто цветные прямоугольники, и данный способ раздробил один из прямоугольников аж на 3 колонки.
Я делаю каталог. И получается, что заголовок каталога у меня в первом столбце внизу, а его элементы во втором столбце вверху - не красиво и непонятно.
Если не найду решения, придётся фиксировать высоту для каждой категории через JS.

Comment: Разбивку можно подавить ``li {  break-inside: avoid; }``

Comment: Спасибо. То что надо. 
Элементы делятся на нужное количество колонок, не дробятся на части.